# Copying vs Moving while casting objects

Tags: c++, oop, casting, move, move-semantics

I am trying to implement a class for linear algebra column vectors. I have the following code snippet, where I try to cast an object without copying anything.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Vector
{
    public:
    std::vector<int> vect;

    public:
    Vector() = default;

    Vector(const Vector& v):vect(v.vect){ };

    Vector(Vector&& v)
    {
        vect.swap(v.vect);
    }

    Vector(const std::vector<int>& v)
    {
        vect = v;
    }

    Vector(std::vector<int>&& v)
    {
        vect.swap(v);
    }

    auto begin()
    {
        return vect.begin();
    }

    auto end()
    {
        return vect.end();
    }
};

class ColumnVector: public Vector
{
    public:
    ColumnVector() = default;

    ColumnVector(const ColumnVector& v)
    {
        this->vect = v.vect;
    }

    ColumnVector(ColumnVector&& v)
    {
        this->vect.swap(v.vect);
    }

    ColumnVector(Vector&& v)
    {
        this->vect.swap(v.vect);
    }
};


int main()
{
    Vector v(vector<int>({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }));

    ColumnVector cv = ( ColumnVector&& )v;

    for ( auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++ )
        cout << *it << " ";
    // nothing printed -- seems that data have been moved

    for ( auto it = cv.begin(); it != cv.end(); it++ )
        cout << *it << " ";
    // 1 2 3 4 5
}
```

I try to cast objects without any copying. The speed is essential, so I was wondering if I'm doing it right. Also, guys, do you have any optimization tricks that I can use for this code snippet?

FINAL:
I decided to use `std::move`, which did the job as fast as possible.

Comment: _"...I was wondering if I'm doing it right...."_ use `std::move` - why because if you make a typo `( ColumnVector&& )` will compile and probably do a `reinterpret_cast` leaving you with Undefined Behaviour. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: A note unrelated to the issue: Using `swap` to implement move assignment/constructor may seem like a simple solution, but it can lead to unexpected order resources being freed, since the object that was the source of the move could survive longer than the target of the move... Also `Vector` is missing a virtual destructor...

Comment: But why do you expect the code to print anything? `ColumnVector cv = ( ColumnVector&& )v;` tells the compiler to use `ColumnVector(ColumnVector&& v)` to construct `cv`, which, assuming there are no problems with undefined behavior, swaps the data out of the vector storing the data of `v` which means `v` is empty afterwards; you print the contents of `v` though, not the ones of `cv`...

Comment: @fabian I have nothing to do in destructor, therefore I don't need one

Comment: @andrei81 That's not entirely true. Your constructor is responsible for deleting the vector, even though you don't need to define a constructor for doing this. In this case you may likely be in luck and there's no data `ColumnVector` adds to `Vector` so it's likely to work in your case, however there's no guarantee that you'll be able to properly delete a dynamically allocated `ColumnVector` which is referenced via `Vector*`, which is something you wouldn't expect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write the copy and move constructors as the compiler will implicitly generate them if the only behavior is to copy/move the `std::vector` member.

By the way, you may want to implement your `ColumnVector` as a view of the `Vector` (something like `std::string_view`) so that there is even no move.